# Adding dynamic variable in the grafana query

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana, dashboard, amazon-eks

I am working over creating grafana queries by using the dynamic variable whose values get populated from the dropdown when the user selects the env.

My query is

```
metric_avg_total{env="$env",job="job1", topic=~"$env_read_val_topic"}
```

The topic value that I want to use is corr to the env.

eg: dev_read_val_topic
qas_read_val_topic

If I write the query as

```
metric_avg_total{env="$env",job="job1", topic=~"dev_read_val_topic"}
```

I am able to see the graph.

But using $env_read_val_topic doesnt replacce the values of the $env with the values selected as env from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following query:

```
metric_avg_total{env="$env",job="job1", topic="${env}_read_val_topic"}
```